# How to launch the terminal automatically on startup?

Tags: lxde, autostart, lxterminal

I use the terminal each time I use Ubuntu so am looking for a way of opening it automatically on each startup.

Currently I'm using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + T` which does the job pretty well but I'd like to avoid this step each time I start my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu open "**Startup applications**".
Open the dash and search for "*Startup applications*".
Click on "**Add**" and add a `gnome-terminal` entry.

- Name : `Terminal`
- Command : `gnome-termnial`

---

[image]

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login?lq=1) for more information on how to launch applications on Ubuntu startup.

Comment: I'm using the LXDE desktop and don't have a menu item for "Startup Applications". How else can I open this?

Comment: For LXDE, go in  **Preferences** > **Default applications for LXSession**  > **Autostart** and then simply check your terminal application ;)

Comment: Great, I've opened Autostart but my terminal app isn't in the list. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no LXDE desktop in front of me but from memory it should be displayed as `lxterminal`. If it is not on the list simply click **Add** and add a new entry with command : `lxterminal`